Confusion with higher order derivatives
Suppose we have a function with double derivative of variable $x$ multiplied by its single derivative..
$$x^{"}.x'=f'(x)$$
We can rewrite the following equation as
$$D(D(x))D(x)=Df(x)$$
While taking the antiderivative, I slabbed the both single derivative of x  inside the same operator.
$$D((D(x))^2)=Df(x)$$
But antiderivative of this equation led  to a false answer..
This thing can easily be resolved by use of different variable. But I don't know why the D operator form doesn't work.
Help is appreciated.
Edit: $x$ is a function of an independent variable and is differentiable..

If this is a function then the second derivative of $x$ should just be zero. Presumably you want to introduce another operator $O$ so that $O f = (D^2 f)(D f)$?

Shouldn't it be $\frac12D((D(x))^2)=Df(x)$ in the last equality?

HINT
Suppose that $x$ is the dependent variable whose associated independent variable is $t$.
Then one obtains:
\begin{align*}
x''(t)x'(t) = f'(x(t)) & \Longleftrightarrow x''(t)[x'(t)]^{2} = f'(x(t))x'(t)
\end{align*}
Now you can apply the chain rule to both sides.
Can you take it from here?

Chain rules works. But I don't know why we can't multiply the two terms to get the same answer.. I know it is satisfy the equality but it less obvious that 1/2 is multiplied.

@Alv sorry, but I did not understand quite well what you meant to say. Could you please rephrase it?

I meant that the third equation doesn't yield the same answer. The expression $D((D(x)2)$
is supposed to be $\frac{D((D(x)^2))}{2}$.

@Alv Notice that $Df(x)\neq f'(x(t))$ in general. They are equal if $x(t) = t + c$.
